# Enabling remote access on Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, remote-access, router

everyone,

I live in a dorm where I don't have access to the router interface, but the network doesn't seem to allow wireless remote access. For example, my iOS Remote, VLC Remote, and other apps that communicate with my Mac can't find the computer. Is there a feature that needs to be checked in the router? I'd like to know so I can discuss it with the admin. This normally works fine in traditional residential networks, but not in public ones.

Thanks in advance!

Mario

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this might be that all users on the network are separated. This is most likely because of security reasons, since people cannot access eachothers computers. I'm sorry but I dont think your admin will allow that. But he might have a soloution to your problem, doesent hurt to ask.

Hope this helped!
-kad